# How do I add a queue to a custom message consumer at run-time

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery, django-celery

I have a use-case where my Django App needs to process messages from an external source. Celery supports this with [Custom Message Consumers](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/extending.html?highlight=ConsumerStep#custom-message-consumers), and this part is working fine.

The exchange type is `headers` so that a message may route to different queues based on conditions. The conditions are configured through the Django Admin. From the code below, you can see, for instance a QueueItem may be activated / inactivated at any time.

This works find on loading a worker for the first time. On a fresh Rabbit, the exchange, queues and routes all get built and the custom consumer consumes messages correctly.

The issue lies when a user adds a new QueueItem or flips the active status of an existing QueueItem. I can dynamically create the new queue, but no matter how hard I try the Custom Consumer does not consume from it. I would like the app to:

1. Relaunch the custom consumer (I tried `app.control.broadcast('pool_restart')`)
2. Add the queues and consume it using the Custom Consumer. (I tried `app.control.add_consumer(...)`)
3. Gracefully restart all workers which when I do manually works to pick up the new settings.

```
class MyConsumerStep(bootsteps.ConsumerStep):
    alias = 'MyConsumerStep'

    def get_queues(self):
        from app.models import QueueItem
        qs = QueueItem.objects.filter(active=True, mode=QueueItem.MODE_ASYNC, direction=QueueItem.DIRECTION_INBOUND)
        return [Queue(q.name, Exchange('qbpubsub', 'headers'),
                      binding_arguments={
                          'var1': q.field1,
                          'var2': q.field2,
                          'x-match': 'any'
                      }) for q in qs]

    def get_consumers(self, channel):
        return [Consumer(channel,
                         queues=self.service_queues,
                         on_message=self.on_message,
                         accept=['json'])]

    def on_message(self, message):
        payload = message.decode()
        print('Received message: {0!r} {props!r} rawlen={s}'.format(
            payload, props=message.properties, s=len(message.body)
        ))
        message.ack()
```

I've been successful at creating a new queue. I've been successful at attaching it to the default celery consumer. I would like to somehow attach it to the custom consumer so the `on_message` callback can process it.

I feel like I'm pretty close but just missing one small obvious part of the Celery / Kombu API.